# Add an angular filter from an external file to mean js stack

Tags: angularjs, mean, angular-filters, meanjs

I'm new to the mean js stack and all of it's sub components.

I want to include a function that will changes the dates from, eg "12/12/14" to "8 weeks ago". I found it here https://gist.github.com/rodyhaddad/5896883/. I think it's a new angular filter.

But how do I include it in my mean js stack? Do I put the file somewhere?

And after that, can I use this "timeago" filter just like any other angular filter? Or is there something special I have to do?

Thanks,
Bran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this code on your module.

```
angular.module('yourName').filter( ....
```

You can place it in any file or in any existing file. If you place it in new file, make sure you include it with `<script src="...">`.

After that you can use it

```
{{variable | timeago}}
<span ng-bind="variable | timeago : null: true"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although, I had to add some dependencies into the all.js file too!